# Есть ли в библиотеке discord.py, событие для входа пользователя в голосовой канал и выхода из него?

Tags: python, discord

Есть ли в библиотеке discord.py, событие для входа пользователя в голосовой канал и выхода из него?

Comment: [How to use discord.py event handler on_voice_state_update to run only when a user joins a voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50477079/2881286)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    elif before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print('1')
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        print('0')
```

При входе пишется - "1", выходе - "0"